# Backup and synchronizinf Gdrive

Tags: backup, sync, google-drive

Since I am a control freak, I like to have a copy  of my professional google drive (I don't keep any confidential file on it) on on my desktop and laptop that I update daily using FreeFileSync. I also keep a copy in a USB stick and on a hard disk, that I update periodically the same way.
I'm doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.10 on my laptop, but left my USB sticks and hard drive at work.

1. How can I copy my Google Drive to my laptop (from the cloud) reasonably fast? Employing FreeFileSync takes almost a day.
2. Any alternative to FreeFileSync that is worth trying to synchronize my files on my machines?

Happy holidays

Matteo

Comment: why backup what is already being backed up by Google? If you accidentally delete a file it remains for some time to be able to recover it 

Comment: A few answers: 1. I'm a control freak; 2. I have to validate the access to Google services through my employer's (a public university) platform, it has been known to have breakdowns, planned and unwanted, which would be inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

How are you mounting/linking to your Google Drive?

Personally I use [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) and `rsync` scripts.

I had bugs/problems using the native Ubuntu connection to Google Drive so changed to google-drive-ocamlfuse. You can mount one or more Google drives and they then act pretty much just like any other drive/mount including supporting most `rsync` features. It may well be faster transferring files but I don't know as never ran any comparisons.

I can't comment on performance as I have not used FreeFileSync. And you would need to specify more info such as how you are connecting/mounting your google drive, how much data is being transferred, network speeds and also how FreeFileSync is configured to check file differences/versions. Syncing could be done by comparing file date/times, file sizes or something else MD5 checksums etc. Some methods will be much quicker than others.

Comment: Syncronizing through FreFileSync is fast enough. It's just creating a local copy of gdrive which is long. I'll test ocamlfuse as well, thanks!